# Syncing data between apps (android) with use of Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, synchronization

I am trying to make an Android app that take data from user, stores it on server and other person(with permission) can view it . Is is possible to do with parse.com? How?
P.S: I have a little idea of Server side

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide check this

Comment: I have checked.. but can't understand

Answer (score 2):

For Storing the data on **parse** server,you have to register on **parse.com**.

Useful link:- 1) https://parse.com/apps/quickstart
              2) https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

**Then follow the steps:-**

**1)** First you have to create your application.After creating an app you will find your app in Select app drop-down.

**2)** Select your app in that you will find some tabs like:-

**A)Settings**:-I that you will find your **client key** and **application id** that you will need at the time of performing operation on server.

**B)Data Browser**:-That will display your records saved from your android app.

From the above guidelines you will get an idea of **server part**.And for your android app you have to write the code of following.

```
    Parse.initialize(this, application_id, client_key);

    // To track statistics around application
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, ShowPopUp.class,
            R.drawable.nxt_btn);

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
            testObject.put("Name", "Born_To_Win");
            testObject.put("Address", "US");
            testObject.put("No", "000000");
            testObject.put("Desc", "Developer");

            testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @SuppressWarnings("null")
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this, "Data Saved Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this, "Data not saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Hope this will helps you or any developer for storing the data on parse server.

Comment: and how will some other person will see it ?

Comment: If I recall correctly there is a way to do permissions like in Lincoln up to say who can access the data so that you could enable all parse users of a certain group or permission access to the data.